# System-config-printer in xubuntu Raring

Tags: 13.04, printing, xubuntu

My system-config-printer in Xubuntu raring is bahaving rather odd, when I click the server settings.

[image: As you see the first option (to show the printers of other systems) is missing]

As you see the first option (to show the printers of other systems) is missing.

My installation is Precise-clean->upgrade to quantal->upgrade to raring.

I tried to compile the newest system-config-printer which is now in version 1.4

[image: about system-config printer]

but the problem persists. I also tried purging system-config-printer-* and reinstalling them back. None worked.

Is this a "feature" in raring, since I can't find anything on the web describing this issue?

Comment: With older version of system-config-printer the option is there but grayed. I think it is the cups' fault. and system-config-printer's

Answer (score 1):

It is a feature, after all. If you have printers that you installed a separate driver in order to work, do **search for network printer** and enter the server's IP address. It will allow you to connect to your printer via IPP and no additional labour needs to be done.